# Route bluetooth tether through VPN?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering, vpn, bluetooth-tethering

With an adb prompt or, failing that, a root prompt, how can I alter default behavior to root traffic through the VPN connection in Android 10 so that this behavior remains when unrooted?

In the case of an Android phone connecting to another Android phone running a bluetooth tether, neither can apply any security precautions to the tethered traffic and this is a bit of a security risk. I need to fix this hole.

Comment: Your question mixes up technologies and is therefore a bit confusing. Hotspots are always Wifi based. I think what you want to describe is "Bluetooth tethering". As far as I remember Bluetooth connections should always be encrypted, the difference is the pairing procedure and therefore how you identify to which other device the connection has been established.

Comment: Got it. I've edited the wording. The VPN is not for encryption. It's for adblocking and generally getting Android to do anything to the connection, like Wireshark, for example, or adguard, or noroot firewall, or NextDNS